# How run barcodescanner in droidgap on android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-applications, cordova

I implement cordova 2.1.0 plugin with PhoneGap but, don't run!! because its have error and don't start!!

```
error:
GC_EXPLICIT freed 52K, 39% free 6070K/9944K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 197ms
.....
cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
Error:
SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
Cause - unable to open database file
external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec'
file:///android_asset/cordova-2.1.0.js: Line 955 : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec'
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/cordova-2.1.0.js:955
onMessage(spinner,stop)
Starting TG #0, 0x49fea1e0
```

its stop in this line!

I've disabled and comment the function "var getLocation = function()" in main.js for don't run and search db but no answer.

I fined http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/07/upgrading-your-phonegap-android.html , beacause used this sample for BarcodScanner in my project

please, help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fined problem for don't work my bar-code scanner, The solution was to extends Activity!!
because, I definition Main class when extends activity, so then all of classes extends Main for reason want implements animation effect for start and end of activity.